# How to use LocationExtractionStrategy in iText to extract from standardized pdf?

Tags: c#, .net, itext, itext7

I have a standardized pdf invoice. I would like to use iText7 to extract certain data elements from the pdf. After an extensive search on the net, I was not able to find any resources or walkthroughs to show how iText7 can be used to extract text from pdf. I can extract fine using `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy`, But i am looking for examples on how to use `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` to extract text from given boxes in a pdf.

I read that you have to locate the "boxes" in your document first, but really coudlnt find any code or information on that. Thanks

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(path);
            PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);
            for (int page = 1; page <= pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages(); page++)
            {
                ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                string pageContent = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfDoc.GetPage(page), strategy);
            }
```

Comment: *"a standardized pdf invoice"* - what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean a pdf file with the same format that will not change.

Comment: By *same format* do you mean that there is a fixed position for everything? Or are there dynamic parts, like tables or lists with variable heights, that make the parts thereunder move?

Comment: Not everything is fixed, there is one table that has the line items on the invoice that will change depending on how many different items on the invoice (1 item, 2 items, 3 items etc)

Comment: Does the content below the table move up or down, depending on the number of items on the list? Or is there a fixed area for the list which partly remains empty for short lists?